# PHP isn't detecting new lines from text file properly

Tags: php, file, text, newline

I have a text file with these contents

```
00:00:00:23 You
00:00:01:04 would
00:00:01:10 not
00:00:01:20 believe
00:00:02:07 your
00:00:02:16 eyes
00:00:03:08 -
00:00:03:16 if
00:00:03:20 ten
00:00:04:01 million
00:00:04:13 fireflies
00:00:06:00 -
00:00:06:08 lit
00:00:06:17 up
00:00:07:01 the
00:00:07:04 world
00:00:07:13 as
```

Notice how between each timestamp there is a new line. If I do file_get_contents and print it it will display in the browser exactly as shown with new line as wanted. However, I want to get each new line as a separate array element. When I use file(), only one element with the whole txt file is returned, and even if I write

```
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
```

at the start of the script, most of the lines are put in arrays but some are not. If I try to explode with the "\n" delimiter, well that doesn't work at all.

Comment: Is it a windows file? Try to explode it on `\r\n`

Comment: nah mac. tried that it didn't work

Comment: you know what, I just copied and pasted the text into some online html converter and pasted it back and it worked fine. Doesn't explain why this is happening tho.

Comment: You might have hidden characters in your text that break things.  try something like this `$text=iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $text);` then break on new line

Comment: Open a terminal and use `od -c your_file_name.txt` to see if there are any weird line-break variations in your file - either `\n` for unix, `\r` for "classic" mac or `\r\n` for windows.

Comment: Had a simmilar issue. I thought i'd add it as info here.
I originally created a file on Windows and continued working on Linux. Had to do chmod on it. At that point php stopped recognizing new line on both systems. So yeah, recreate a file or copy paste into a agnostic system like online converter like you said

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('foo.txt'));
```

also try to explode on: "\025" or "\r"

> latest example, please try this one:

also try:

```
<?php
$lines =file_get_contents('foo.txt');
$lines = preg_split("/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/", $lines);
print_r($lines);
?>
```

Comment: nope, told you i already tried explode, but not with \025, but that still didn't work

Comment: I have an updated example above, this expression has a chance to properly detect new lines: "/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/" can you try again? Can you update your file to some location so we can use it?

Comment: Please use the solution which includes preg_split("/\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/", $lines);

Here is what I have done to test if this works:I have saved file with Mac line ending options in PSPad Editor then I have tried all three options (\n,\025,\r) none of them worked, however /\\r\\n|\\r|\\n/ gives the desired output:

Array ( [0] => 00:00:00:23 You [1] => 00:00:01:04 would [2] => 00:00:01:10 not...